# Access 2000 getting #Name? when running query programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Form in Access 2000 bound to a table. When you open this form all the textbox and dropdowns work fine. I have a combobox where a user selects a option. Depending on what is selected, a query is run. When I do this all the Textbox that are link to their assign field in the table work fine but one. I have even tried to assigned it promatically. I get the error #Name?.  I know it means that is not finding it but why. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code behind where I run the query programmatically and a screenshot of the error that I get.

```
Public Sub Select_Table(LineNumber As Integer, kvaNumber As Integer)

Dim strlineNumber As String

Select Case LineNumber

   Case 0
      strlineNumber = "52"
   Case 1
      strlineNumber = "53"
   Case 2
      strlineNumber = "54"
   Case 3
      strlineNumber = "55"
End Select

 Dim message As Integer
 Dim param As String



Select Case kvaNumber
        Case 0
            txt_DesignEngineer.ControlSource = "Design_Engineer_2"                
            Me.RecordSource = "SELECT [Sequence Number], [Design_Engineer_2], [ED Plan Start], [ED Plan Finish], [Prel Person], [Prel Plan Start], [Prel Plan Finish], [Catalog No], [Internal Designer], [Int Plan Start], [Int Plan Finish], [External Designer], [Ext Plan Start], [Ext Plan Finish], [OTL Plan Start], [OTL Plan Finish], [Control Engineer], [Cnl Plan Start], [Cnl Plan Finish] FROM [Engineering Schedule 2] WHERE [Catalog No] LIKE '" & strlineNumber & "03*' ORDER BY [Sequence Number]"
        Case 1

     End Select


End Sub
```

[image: Error Form]

Comment: Sorry it is a combobox but by mistake I name it txt_DesignEngineer

Comment: Are the items in Design_Engineer_2 items that are in whatever your rowsource for the combobox?

Comment: @KevenDenen Yes they are populated from a table called ElectricalDesigner.  Row Source...... ElectricalDesigners. Any Ideas or sugestions why this is happening ? Thanks